# Symfony 2.7 cache:clear command checks every database connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just have upgraded to symfony 2.7, and have a annoying behaviour.

Some connections in my config.yml are optionables, and describe foreign databases that are not intended to be used in every prod instances.

When doing a cache:clear , it seems that now every connections are checked, even if I don't want them to be active on a particular server.

When setting the --no-warmup option, the problem occurs half the time

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup --verbose
```

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown
>   database 'bal_syncrho_database'
>
> Exception trace:  () at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver->convertException() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DBALException.php:133
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException::driverException() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php:47
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:360
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:429
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:389
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->detectDatabasePlatform() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:328
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatform() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:763
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getTargetPlatform() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:616
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->completeIdGeneratorMapping()
>   at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:174
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:332
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata()
>   at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php:78
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:216
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor()
>   at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:115
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getAllMetadata()
>   at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/CacheWarmer/ProxyCacheWarmer.php:69
>   Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\CacheWarmer\ProxyCacheWarmer->warmUp() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/CacheWarmer/CacheWarmerAggregate.php:48
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheWarmer\CacheWarmerAggregate->warmUp()
>   at /var/www/ror3/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2641 
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() at
>   /var/www/ror3/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2411 
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at
>   /var/www/ror3/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:120
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at
>   /var/www/ror3/app/console:27

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Doctrine is trying to determine the Database Platform Version.

You can avoid this behavior by adding the server version in the [Doctrine DBAL Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration). From the doc:

> The server_version option was added in Doctrine DBAL 2.5, which is
> used by DoctrineBundle 1.3. The value of this option should match your
> database server version (use postgres -V or psql -V command to find
> your PostgreSQL version and mysql -V to get your MySQL version).
>
> **If you don't define this option and haven't created your database yet, you may get PDOException errors because Doctrine will
> try to guess the database server version automatically and none is
> available.**

As example:

```
#config.yml

doctrine:
    dbal:
    ...
        server_version:       5.6
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In case you dont bundle the MySQL extension with your PHP build, and use an alternate DB like PostGres, you might get errors like "Driver.php could not find driver" as Doctrine is attempting to try MySQL even though it is not configured for MySQL.
As expected, setting the `driver` property plus `server_version` resolves the issue.