# Symfony2 Track Database access call on composer install

Tags: symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I would need advices to figure out how to see which bundle/class/portion of code tries to access the database on Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

Indeed during the composer install process. I get the following error message.

> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>       [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>           An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

I am wondering why the database needs to be called at this stage and by whom ?

in advance thanks.

Comment: Hi, check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023813/symfony-2-7-cacheclear-command-checks-every-database-connection/34024275#34024275

Comment: Hi, thanks Matteo. It was indeed my pb.