# php symfony in docker

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I have a dockerfile to start a symfony server.
The Dockerfile contains:

```
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader
RUN APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
RUN php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=prod --dump-sql --force
```

If `build` it in the docker network with the mysql running, it runs fine. But if i build it wihthout the mysql being available it fails because:

```
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php(27): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'USER', 'PASSWD', Array)
!!  #1 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOMySql/Driver.php(25): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection->__construct('mysql:host=mysq...', 'USER', 'PASSWD', Array)
!!  #2 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(362): Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver->connect(Array, 'root', 'massphoning', Array)
!!  #3 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(428): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->connect()
!!  #4 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php(388): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getDatabasePlatformVersion()
!!  #5 /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connecti in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php on line 93
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

I don't really know symfony, but I'm guessing symfony is trying to create some db pool and tries to actually make the connection to the db.
But if I'm `build`ing the docker, there won't be a db server available!
How can i make symfony *not* test the db connection?

Comment: Did this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34024275/6759119

Comment: `RUN php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --env=prod --dump-sql --force` command requires the db connection

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the reason for making such logic as schema update in Dockerfile, Dockerfile should allow to create environment, contains required dependencies and nothing else.

So, please look at this https://github.com/AndreyMashukov/crassula

this is example of Symfony 5 project, I hope, it will help you. It has an example of Dockerfile with Xdebug extension for php and some tests (unit, functional) and CI example